# Page specific css stylesheets in Rails (using two different versions of twitter bootstrap)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I've started a Rails project and implemented bootstrap-sass into it. A short time later I found a theme/template using a different version of twitter bootstrap. I've added the template to the app but the view doesn't align perfectly as was intended. I then added the specific assets that came with the theme/template to my project (such as jquery version, ANOTHER older bootstrap version) and the result is almost perfect. However, there are still some alignment issues. When I inspect the CSS I can see it's happening because of conflicts between the two versions of bootstrap.

I'm thinking I should make it so that this template only uses the version of twitter bootstrap that came with it. If so, how do I do this? How do I make it so that a rails view will only use a certain css stylesheet and not read from others?

(If this is not the best solution, what are some alternatives I should consider?)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

1) use 2 layouts (application.html.erb and new_application.html.erb)
2) have two master javascript/css file (application.js and new_application.js, application.css and new_application.css)
3) inside your application.html.erb include the first application.js and application.css, on your second layout, import the new application js and css
4) for the specific parts of your page, on the controlle inherit from the right parent controller for whichever layout you want.

```
class NewBootstrapController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'new_application'
end

class OldBootstrapController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'application'
end
```

Comment: i did this but rather then specifying the layout in the controllers i created two layouts, each pulling its own assets (declared in `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to try to view your project as consisting of "components" rather than pages. So focus on keeping the styling for your components up-to-date and consistent.

So rather than coding for individual pages, which doesn't scale and is difficult to maintain even with small(ish) projects, look for ways to turn elements into reusable components. Bootstrap is this way by default, so if there are certain components you use more than others, make those the priority for refactoring, and then look for repeating patterns across your pages and try to think about how you can create semantic, component-based classes to describe them.

Instead of this:

```
.sidebar-home {}
```

Try this:

```
.sidebar-narrow {} // or whatever describes your element
```

The operative point here is that if you will ever work on more than this project, get into the good habit of thinking about your CSS/HTML as consisting of components, and you will be able to reuse code and become much faster at identifying patterns in your UI.